# Quitar caracteres de un csv a la hora de imprimirlo en consola

Tags: python, python-2.7

Tuve el siguiente problema en `python` con archivos `csv`, estaba intentando quitar salidas del `csv` a la consola que no quiero que aparezcan y no toma mi condición.

```
with open("/home/franco/Desktop/Python/hum.csv","r") as archivo:
    lineas = archivo.read()
    for l in lineas:
        linea = l.split(',')
        if (linea != '\n' or linea != 'b' or linea != '\r'):
            print (linea)
```

Y la salida que me da es la siguiente 
:

[image: Esa es la salida que me de[1]]

¿Cómo logro quedarme con los numero del `csv`?

Answer (score 1):

Primero de todo, **no estás leyendo líneas, lees caracteres uno a uno**. Cuando haces `lineas = archivo.read()` no obtienes una lista de lineas, obtienes una cadena con el contenido completo de tu archivo. Luego, al iterar con el `for` lo que haces es ir leyendo carácter a carácter, uno a uno.

> ```
> >>> lineas = "soy una cadena"
> >>> for linea in lineas:
>         print(linea)
>
> 's'
> 'o'
> 'y'
> ' '
> 'u'
> 'n'
> 'a'
> ' '
> 'c'
> 'a'
> 'd'
> 'e'
> 'n'
> 'a'
> ```

Luego sobre cada "linea" aplicas `split`, el cual no sirve para nada ya que no tienes nada que partir al recibir siempre un solo carácter. Simplemente se limita a retornar una lista con ese carácter como único elemento:

```
>>> "b".split(",")
['b']
```

Lo anterior hace que **el condicional no sirva para nada, dado que `linea` es una lista en este punto, no una cadena**, por lo que siempre se cumple la condición del `if`. La comparación es realmente `['\n'] =! '\n'` (por ejemplo), lo que es cierto siempre porque comparas dos objetos distintos, uno es una  lista (`list`) y el otro objeto una cadena (`str`).

Si quieres obtener los datos de tu csv manualmente, sin usar el módulo `csv` de la stdlib, el procedimiento sería:

- Para iterar línea a linea sobre un archivo cualquiera  no uses `read` o `readlines` nunca, esto es muy ineficiente ya que cargas el archivo en memoria al completo. En su lugar simplemente itera sobre él  con un `for-in`.
- Usa `str.rstrip` sobre cada linea para eliminar el carácter de nueva linea (`\n`, `\rn`, `\r`).
- Por último aplica `str.split` para partir la cadena usando el separador de turno.

Para un archivo con el siguiente contenido:

> Nombre,Edad\r\n
>   Antonio,14\r\n
>   María,12\r\n

puedes hacer:

```
with open("ejemplo.csv", "r") as archivo:
    cabecera = next(archivo).rstrip("\r\n")
    print(cabecera)
    print("--------------")
    for linea in archivo:
        fila = linea.rstrip("\r\n").split(',')
        print(fila)
```

con lo que obtienes:

> ```
> ['Nombre', 'Edad']    
> --------------
> ['Antonio', '14']        
> ['María', '12']
> ```

En este caso `linea` es una lista con los valores para cada columna de esa fila. Por otro lado, `cabecera = next(archivo)` sirve para obtener la primera línea del archivo antes de iterar con el `for`. Esto es útil si la primera fila contiene los nombres de las columnas, si el archivo no tiene cabecera entonces debemos prescindir de esto. Si solo quisieras la segunda columna basta con indexar, p.ej `print(fila[1])`

No obstante, en condiciones normales considera usar el módulo [csv](https://docs.python.org/3/library/csv.html) para esto, facilita mucho la tarea de lectura o escritura de archivos csv:

```
import csv

with open("ejemplo.csv", "r") as archivo:
    reader = csv.reader(archivo, delimiter=',')
    cabecera = next(reader)
    print(cabecera)
    print("--------------")
    for fila in reader:
        print(fila)
```

O bien usando [`DictReader`](https://docs.python.org/3/library/csv.html#csv.DictReader), con lo que obtienes un diccionario/`collections.OrderedDict` por cada fila en el que las claves son el nombre de la columna y los valores el valor de cada celda de esa fila para esa columna:

```
with open("ejemplo.csv", "r") as archivo:
     reader = csv.DictReader(archivo, delimiter=',')
     for fila in reader:
         print(fila)
```

> ```
> OrderedDict([('Nombre', 'Antonio'), ('Edad', '14')])
> OrderedDict([('Nombre', 'María'), ('Edad', '12')])
> ```

Esto facilita el acceso a cada columna usando el nombre de la misma:

```
with open("ejemplo.csv", "r") as archivo:
     reader = csv.DictReader(archivo, delimiter=',')
     for fila in reader:
         print "Nombre:", fila["Nombre"]
         print "Edad:", fila["Edad"], "\n"
```

> ```
> Nombre: Antonio
> Edad: 14 
>
> Nombre: María
> Edad: 12
> ```